# How do I move my cursor to a mesh's origin?

Tags: mesh, origin, 3d-cursor

I'm struggling with how to put my cursor to a mesh's origin point (all axes XYZ), not just in front of the mesh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the object and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*

Comment: ty for the ez input

Answer (score 4):

Right click the object, select "snap", and choose "cursor to selected" in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can move an object to the 3D Cursor by selecting *Selection to Cursor* instead.

Comment: This changes mesh' position, which may be undesired.